# VC++ 2008: DLL import gone haywire - What could be causing this?

Tags: linker, visual-c++

The VC++2008 linker for some reason isn't creating proper imports for a DLL I'm working on. The import section should look like this:

[image]

What I'm getting is this:

[image]

Somehow the linker is attaching functions belonging to phpts.dll to the other DLLs.

Any hint as to what might be causing this?

UPDATE: If I change the linker setting "Generate Debug Info" to yes, then it links correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out that the import libraries I downloaded were broken. Recreating them from the .def files fixes the problem.